# mediaelementjs event pause after playing new stream

Tags: javascript, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I use last version of mediaelementjs (v7) and it works well but I have just a little problem, I use this script:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.header a[rel=open_player]', function() {
        var bottom_player = $(document).find('.bottom-player');
        var webradio_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        isPlaying = true;
        var currentStream;

        $.post('/ajax/webradio/'+ webradio_id, function(data) {
            bottom_player.html(data);
            var player = bottom_player.find('audio');
            
            player.mediaelementplayer({
                audioWidth: '100%',
                pluginPath: '/assets/public/js/mediaelement/',
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                features: ['playpause','volume'],
                audioVolume: 'horizontal',
                isVideo: false,
                forceLive: true,
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                    mediaElement.play();
                    currentStream = mediaElement.getSrc();
                    mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function () {
                        console.log('['+Date.now() + '] Media play: getSrc='+ mediaElement.getSrc()+' / currentStream='+currentStream);
                    document.title = '\u25B6 ' + origTitle;
                    isPlaying = true;
                }, false);
                mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
                    if(currentStream == mediaElement.getSrc()) {
                         console.log('['+Date.now() + '] Media pause: getSrc='+ mediaElement.getSrc() + ' / currentStream='+currentStream);  // Log de l'état du listener
                         document.title = origTitle;
                         isPlaying = false;
                     }
                }, false);
            },
        });
    });
```

My problem is when I play a stream, in the console I have: "Media play", and when I click on another stream to play it instead of the first, in the console I have: "Media play" "Media pause" but it plays well the new stream. My problem is that I have isPlaying = false because "pause" Event is fired after play.

Console logs:

```
[1695287178446] Media play: getSrc=https://example.com/stream-wr03.aac?i=94884 / currentStream=https://example.com/stream-wr03.aac?i=94884
[1695287178449] Media pause: getSrc=https://example.com/stream-01.aac?i=30130 / currentStream=https://example.com/stream-01.aac?i=30130
[1695287190405] Media play: getSrc=https://example.com/stream-wr01.aac?i=24717 / currentStream=https://example.com/stream-wr01.aac?i=24717
[1695287190409] Media pause: getSrc=https://example.com/stream-wr03.aac?i=94884 / currentStream=https://example.com/stream-wr03.aac?i=94884
```

Any idea to avoid that?

Comment: What does the `getSrc` method return inside each of those two event handlers? If one is the new source, and the other one the old - then maybe you could compare the two, to determine whether `pause` happened because the user paused the current video, or because the stream changed ...?

Comment: _"and when I click on another stream to play it instead of the first"_ - is that switching of streams even happening "within" this player script? Or are you initializing a new player for a new video source?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I add getSrc(), my console display this:
Média play https://domain.ch/stream-03.aac?i=63553
Média pause https://domain.ch/stream-01.aac?i=74342

Média play https://domain.ch/stream-02.aac?i=63553
Média pause https://domain.ch/stream-03.aac?i=29759

but if I add a var currentStream in play event, as the play event is fired before the pause event, when the pause event occurs, currentStream is already the new stream...

Comment: _"Or are you initializing a new player for a new video source?"_ it's always the same player

Comment: _"my console display this:"_ - can't really tell from this, at which point you just paused the current stream, and at which you switched to a different one. _"but if I add a var currentStream in play event, as the play event is fired before the pause event, when the pause event occurs, currentStream is already the new stream..."_ - then keep a reference to the _previous_ stream as well, and compare both - and set isPlaying accordingly.

Comment: I've updated my source code in my answer, and added console logs, even when I keep a reference to the previous stream, it doesn't work..

Comment: _"even when I keep a reference to the previous stream, it doesn't work"_ - I don't see where you would have actually tried that, in the shown code. And setting the `currentStream` happens in the wrong place as well, I think. You should do that _inside_ the `play` event callback. In the `pause` handler you check if you _have_ a previousStream stored already, and if so you check if they are the same or not. And then you set `previousStream = currentStream` (still inside the `pause` handler, after you performed the check), so that you will have that available in the _next_ "cycle" then.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, I set currentStream in "success" function just after mediaElement.play();

Comment: I am saying, do it inside the `play` event callback function, the one you are assigning with `mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function() { ...} )`

Comment: Ok, it's what I've done just before, the result is the same: it seems that mediaelementjs calls "play" always before "pause", so "play event" set new currentStream, and "pause event" is called after so "pause" already have new currentStream, impossible to compare with getSrc() like this

Comment: It is hard to try and reproduce all of this only "theoretically", without having an actual live example to play with. Please clarify, _how_ does switching to a different stream work here. You have multiple of those `a[rel=open_player]` elements, and each one is supposed to play a different stream, is that it? You are calling `player.mediaelementplayer()` each time again then, so I would assume that your play and pause event handlers "stack up" - [...]

Comment: [...] and that the `pause` event handler you see firing, isn't actually the pause handler added when the _current_ link was clicked, but still the one created when the previous one was clicked. I think you should go check the docs to see if this has a different method to switch out the playing stream, without creating a new player instance each time, or if it has some "destroy" method to get rid of the existing one ...

Comment: You can take a look here: niceradio.com, player is at the bottom and to change stream it's with radios icons at the top right (on desktop version)